# multiple null terminated strings in single buffer in C

Tags: c, string, buffer, packing

In need to craft a string with the following format and place it into a single buffer[1000]. Note that \x00 is the null terminator.

```
@/foo\x00ACTION=add\x00SUBSYSTEM=block\x00DEVPATH=/devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0\x00MAJOR=command\x00MINOR=1\x00DEVTYPE=harder\x00PARTN=1
```

So in essence I need to pack following null terminated strings into a single buffer

```
@/foo  
ACTION=add  
SUBSYSTEM=block  
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0  
MAJOR=command  
MINOR=1  
DEVTYPE=harder  
PARTN=1
```

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: `char buffer[1000] = "@/foo\000ACTION=add\000SUBSYSTEM=block\000` ... etc pp.

Comment: `"foo\x00ACTION"` doesn't work, because `\x00AC` is seen as a single character here (A and C are also hex digits), if that confused you.

Comment: instead of `\x00` you can use `\0` which will avoid the issue with `\x00AC` getting treated as a wide char, as a matter of fact `\0` is the preferred C way to specify `NUL`

Comment: how are you getting this *list* of strings? reason for asking is that there may be a much faster way to do this depending on where they're coming from

Comment: @AhmedMasud I'd prefer `\000`, since when you have two strings "abc" "123", `"abc\0123"` does not the expected

Comment: @Ctx that is probably best :-) as the octal will avoid any 'widechar' issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to copy each string in one at a time, keeping track of where the last copy stopped and starting just after that for the next one.

```
char *p = buffer;
strcpy(p, "@/foo");
p += strlen(p) + 1;
strcpy(p, "ACTION=add");
p += strlen(p) + 1;
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%c` to print numeric zero with `sprintf`, like this:

```
char *a[] = {"quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps"};
int n = 0;
char buf[100];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
    n += sprintf(buf+n, "%s%c", a[i], 0);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mPaMqZ)

Comment: Or, a bit easier, `n += sprintf(buf+n, "%s%c", a[i], 0);`

Comment: @Ctx You are right, thanks! I wasn't sure that `printf`'s return value would include the trailing zero without interpreting it as a null terminator.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize your buffer with a string containing explicit embedded NUL characters:

```
char buffer[1000] =
  "@/foo\0"
  "ACTION=add\0"
  "SUBSYSTEM=block\0"  
  "DEVPATH=/devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0\0"
  "MAJOR=command\0"
  "MINOR=1\0"
  "DEVTYPE=harder\0"  
  "PARTN=1";
```

Or you can copy it explicitly with `memcpy`:

```
char str[] =
  "@/foo\0"
  "ACTION=add\0"
  "SUBSYSTEM=block\0"  
  "DEVPATH=/devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0\0"
  "MAJOR=command\0"
  "MINOR=1\0"
  "DEVTYPE=harder\0"  
  "PARTN=1";
char buffer[1000];

memcpy(buffer, str, sizeof(str));
```

Here, the compiler will concatenate adjacent string constants, but only the last string will get an implicit NUL; all others have an explicit NUL.

Also, breaking up a string like `"\01"` (which doesn't actually appear in this case) into `"\0" "1"` prevents the compiler from seeing the `"\01"` as the single character string `{ 0x01, 0x00 }` (with implicit trailing NUL), and instead treats is as the two character string `{ 0x00, 0x31, 0x00 }` (also with an implicit trailing NUL) that was intended.